# How can I turn condition back to False without breaking this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, boolean, logic

I'm working with this Hangman game and this part is for keeping track of the player's lives. It pulls a random word from a list, then it takes the word and turns it into blanks (_). If you guess right, it fills the blanks with the letter and when you guess all the correct letters, you win. If you guess wrong, it is suppose to load a stick figure slowly showing on a noose, like the old school hangman game.

If you guess wrong, you get the first item on the list shown above the code, called 'stages'. When you guess wrong 6 times, you get a message saying 'You lost'. Here is the problem...

When I enter it wrong, it works fine and it even works fine after entering it 6 times wrong. The variable 'lives' goes down minus 1 until it goes to 0. When it hits 0, game over. When I guess right, it works, but if I try to guess wrong, it never detects it being wrong.

The reason is because the variable 'found_letter' is set to False by default, and when you get it correct, it sets it to True. And it doesn't go back to False. Trying to switch to False again leads to other problems.

Here is the code:

```
stages = [''' 
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']


word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]


import random
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

#To-do 1: - Create a variable called 'lives' to keep track of the number of lives left. Set 'lives' equal to 6
lives = 6
found_letter = False
#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

#Create blanks
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
    letter = "_"
    display += letter


while ("_") in display and lives > 0:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    print(("_") in display and lives > 0)

    for letter in range(len(chosen_word)):
        if guess == chosen_word[letter]:
            display[letter] = guess
            found_letter = True
    print(display)


#To-do 2: - If guess is not a letter in the 'chosen'word', then reduce 'lives' by 1. If 'lives' goes down to 0 then the
#game should stop and it should print "You lose."
    # for letter in range(len(chosen_word)):

    if found_letter == False:
        lives -= 1
        print(stages[lives])



    if lives == 0:
        print("You lose.")

print("You have won!")

#To-do 3: - print the ASCII art from 'stages' that corresponds to the current number of 'lives' the user has remaining.
```

When I set the variable 'found_letter' to False under the for loop that sets it to True, it makes the 'stages' figures show up even if you guess correctly. So guessing right after setting to False makes 'lives' in the code above lose 1 anyway.

What I am expecting is that when you guess correctly, it doesn't give you any 'stages' figures and when you guess wrong after guessing right, it detects it works, but it doesn't as the variable 'found_letter' never reverts to False.

I have attempted to move the indent for the bottom code where if checks if found_letter equals False. I have even attempted to change the condition to make it similar to the for loop and took parts of the while loop to check multiple conditions, but whenever I set 'found_letter' to False, it breaks the game by generating figures from 'stages' and reducing 'lives' by 1.

I am failing in figuring out the logic. I am struggling to get better at working with logic in programming. Can you guys also provide tips or tricks? I know this place is for figuring out solutions for coding problems but I need help because that is where I struggle the most. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting it to False. Post the code that has the problem you're describing.

Comment: Put `found_letter = False` right *before* the loop, not after it.

Comment: @Barmar I was going to say the opposite, OP has `found_letter = False` before the loop instead they should set it at the start of each loop, i.e. immediately after the while statement, to make it go back to `False`.

Comment: @SurajShourie I meant before the `for` loop, not the `while` loop. Specifically before `for letter in range(len(chosen_word)):`

Comment: @Barmar that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

In testing out your code, it became evident that there needed to be a reset of the "found_letter" Boolean variable to a value of "False" after each guess in order to produce the desired functionality.  Following is a refactored version of your code.

```
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

import random
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

#To-do 1: - Create a variable called 'lives' to keep track of the number of lives left. Set 'lives' equal to 6
lives = 6

#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

#Create blanks
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
    letter = "_"
    display += letter

while ("_") in display and lives > 0:
    found_letter = False                # Set this to a default of False here before every guess
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    #print(("_") in display)            # Removed this as it was always printing True if even one letter position was "_"

    for letter in range(len(chosen_word)):
        if guess == chosen_word[letter]:
            display[letter] = guess
            found_letter = True         # Now is the time to denote that a letter was guessed correctly
    print(display)

# To-do 2: - If guess is not a letter in the 'chosen'word', then reduce 'lives' by 1. 
# If 'lives' goes down to 0 then the game should stop and it should print "You lose."
# for letter in range(len(chosen_word)):

    if found_letter == False:
        lives -= 1
        print(stages[lives])

#If this point is reached determine if the game was won or lost

if lives == 0:
    print("You lose.")
else:
    print("You have won!")
```

FYI, I omitted the staging figure sets to concentrate on the refactored parts.  Following are some of the key revisions.

- The "found_letter" variable is continually reset to a value of False during each test within the "while" loop.
- The "found_letter" variable is only set to a value of True if a guess matches up with one of the letters within the secret word.
- Since the game continues with testing in the "while" loop when there is at least one location with a "_" character the condition of the print statement that tests for that character gives a spurious True answer that is misleading, so it was deactivated.
- Once either all live are exhausted or the word is guessed, then a check is made to see if the word was correctly guessed or the player ran out of lives, and the appropriate "win/lose" verbiage is printed.

Giving it a test run, following is some of the final lines of output at the terminal.

```
Guess a letter: e
['_', '_', 'd', '_', '_', '_', '_']

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========

Guess a letter: v
['_', '_', 'd', 'v', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter: t
['_', '_', 'd', 'v', '_', '_', '_']
 
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========

You lose.
```

FYI, the word for this game was "ardvark".

This is just one of various ways to move your game forward.  Review it to see if it meets your needs.  As always, go ahead and refer to further python tutorials in the use of conditional testing and Boolean variables.

Comment: That is such an awesome fix! Funny thing is that when I was testing it, I was placing the False statement in places after the True one. I never thought for once that it should be placed False in the while loop as it was already set to False, but it makes perfect sense!