# How can I fix this code to write letters in the correct place for a hangman game?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am taking an introductory computer science class based on Python. A project I am working on is making a hangman game using the Python turtle graphics. What I want this code to be able to do is write out the letters of the word that the user guesses correctly and draw a certain part of the hangman when the user guesses incorrectly. Right now, when the user correctly guesses a letter, the program is writing the letter but not in the correct spot and sometimes not at all.

In my current version, I have a for loop iterating through the letters of the current word. If the letter the user guesses is the same as a letter in the word, the turtle (word_typer) is meant to write that letter in its correct place on the screen. I have this for loop in a while loop in which I also had the variable "place" to keep track of which letter was being written but this still doesn't seem to be working.

```
wrong_guesses = 0
guess_letter = ""
wrong_letters = 0

play = input("The theme of this hangman is chemistry! Would you like to play? y/n ")

def run():
    global play, wrong_guesses, current_word, wrong_letters
    if (play.lower() == 'y'):
        new_word()
        place = 0
        while (wrong_guesses < 6):
            guess_letter = input('Please guess a letter ')
            letters_guessed.append(guess_letter)
            for letter in current_word:
                if guess_letter == letter:
                    word_typer.penup()
                    word_typer.goto(30 * place, 0)
                    word_typer.write(guess_letter, font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
                    place += 1
            for i in current_word:
                if guess_letter != i:
                    wrong_letters += 1
            if wrong_letters == len(current_word):
                wrong_guesses += 1
                draw_hangman()
    else:
        print("Maybe next time!")
```

Comment: `place += 1` is only executed if the current letter is the guessed letter but should be executed if not, too. It should be outside of the if-block. A more Pythonic way would be to use `enumerate` for the for-loop.

Comment: I will refer you to this question and answer I worked on last month "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370359/how-can-i-turn-condition-back-to-false-without-breaking-this-code/77370496#77370496".

Comment: This program doesn't work on a basic level, probably missing some critical pieces (imports for starters). Can you fix the basic problems that are getting in the way of a [mcve] so it's possible to focus on the logic problem you're really asking about? For example, `NameError: name 'play' is not defined. Did you mean: 'place'?` and `run()` is never called, among other distractions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well , I didn't find enough information from the code which you have published , could you send the whole code?

Also I managed to modify the code in a way where it will work without errors (it was missing some variables).

```
wrong_guesses = 0
guess_letter = ""
wrong_letters = 0
letters_guessed = [] #stores the letter which are guessed by users

play = input("The theme of this hangman is chemistry! Would you like to play? y/n ")

def run():
    global wrong_guesses, current_word, wrong_letters
    if (play.lower() == 'y'):
        new_word() #should generate a new word and add it to current_word
        place = 0
        while (wrong_guesses < len(curent_word)):
            guess_letter = input('Please guess a letter ')
            letters_guessed.append(guess_letter)
            for letter in current_word:
                if letter == guess_letter:
                    word_typer.penup()
                    word_typer.goto(30 * place, 0)
                    word_typer.write(guess_letter, font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
                    place += 1
                elif letter != guess_letter:
                    wrong_letters += 1
```

Hope this code helps you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).